# Mocking a deletion in rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, cucumber

I want to mock a deletion without actually deleting anything. For example, past reservations at a restaurant. For legal purposes, the app. can't actually be deleted. Initially I had something similar to this:

When I delete a past reservation do
  ...
  delete("/reservations/...)
end

I have set a boolean on the reservations table that will indicate if the reservation is active/inactive.

I'm not sure what my destroy action will look like.
What can I do get around this constraint, since I can not use the delete verb? I'm stumped.

Comment: There are a bunch of gems that handle soft deletes for you. There's a whole list here https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Soft_Delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly common behaviour

keep everything the same in the controller but in the destroy method, instead of deleting the record, mark it archived, (or whatever your term is for it)

such as

```
@reservation.update_attribute(:archived, true)
```

You should also have scopes that address the archived attribute, such as:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, -> {
    where(archived:false)
  }

  scope :archived, -> {
    where(archived:true)
  }
end
```

Comment: What then would my cucumber request look like? Can I still use this >>> delete("/reservations/...)

Comment: Your cucumber would be exactly the same.. you would be using the same urls after ll..